# Going to fullscreen mode resizes width in IE

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer, fullscreen

[On this link I put a demo which is not working correctly in IE](http://tiborzsitva.szm.com/screenfull/screenfull.html)

Other browsers (Firefox and Chrome) are okay.

The problem is that when going to fullscreen mode the yellow `<div></div>` loses its maximum width. This happens only in stupid IE. It's strange when pressing F11 this problem doesn't occur

Is it possible to go to fullscreen mode with keeping the width of elements?

[This screenfull library is used in my page](https://github.com/sindresorhus/screenfull.js/blob/gh-pages/src/screenfull.js)

Answer (score 1):

ok, I figured out what is the problem, I just needed to add `style="width:100%"` to `<html>` tag.

Comment: OR create a CSS rule for html { width: 100%; }